# IExceptionFilter in minimal .NET 7 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

In my ASP.NET Core app I was registering an `IExceptionFilter` to globally catch exceptions and replace the `Result` returned to the client. I'm now switching to the minimal API way of doing things, but I'm not finding where I register that filter.

In the ASP.NET Core version I'd register that filter in the `AddController` method.

I then tried doing this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseExceptionHandler(x => {
    x.Run(async context => {
        var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()!.Error;

        var details = new ProblemDetails {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            Title = "An unexpected error occurred",
            Detail = exception.Message
        };

        switch (exception) {
            case DisplayToUserException:
                details.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Display-To-User", exception.Message);
                break;
            case ...
        }

        await Results.Problem(details).ExecuteAsync(context);
    });
});
```

That doesn't seem to change the response though.

Also, according to the docs, that only works in production mode.  I need it to work in debug mode as well though because I'm using this to simplify return values.  If something deep in a repository throws an exception, I want the response to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

While Minimal APIs support adding [filters to endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) usual approach for handling exceptions in modern ASP.NET Core including Minimal APIs is by using corresponding middlewares. For example:

```cs
// register it closer to the start of the handling pipeline
app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp 
    => exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context 
        => await Results.Problem()
                     .ExecuteAsync(context)));

app.Map("/exception", () 
    => { throw new InvalidOperationException("Sample Exception"); });
```

Read more:

- [How to handle errors in Minimal API apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/handle-errrors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I updated my question to show trying to use that and the two issues I see with that.

Comment: @Gargoyle tried your code - works fine for me in my repro. Can you please share a [mre]?