# Custom IExceptionFilter on minimal api endpoint

Tags: .net, minimal-apis

```
public class MyExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

how can I register this filter on a specific net 7 minimal API endpoint?

Comment: Taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76623446/7450780)?